# Astrill Applet Application Disappears on Minimize

Tags: 11.10, unity

I'm using the Astrill applet for Linux on Ubuntu 11.10. Up to 11.04 it would work fine and create an icon in the system tray. However in 11.10 Astrill's applet opens just fine however when I minimize it the application simply disappears. There are no icons in the system tray nor in the unity bar. I install tint2 (task bar) to see if I can see the application there but no luck. I know the application is running because I can see it when I execute `ps -aux` (and also because my traffic is being VPN'ed) is there a way I can bring the application in the foreground?

I talked to Astrill's tech support, they weren't very helpful, basically they "think" that they have customers running their applet on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not figure out how to restore the application once you shrink it, but I have a workaround. Use workspace switcher. Keep Astrill open in one of the windows. Then open your browser or whatever in another window. In this way you can keep Astrill open and accessible without it staying on top of your browser.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Well, actually I just configured the built in VPN capability to use Astrill instead of using their applet.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed long time ago by Astrill. Astrill VPN client works great on many Linux platforms, including latest Ubuntu.

You can download latest version of Astrill VPN client from  [Astrill download page](https://www.astrill.com/download.php)